# QT Settings Even If User Close

Tags: qt, save, setting

I have a gui project in Qt. And this project has a lang. file. I can change lang. option. But I want to save this choose for user. I mean if user change lang. Keep it the same even if user close and open it

Comment: Have a look at [QSettings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `QSettings` api to persist settings. For example:

To save a setting:

```
QSettings settings("organization", "name");
//Replace en_US with anything
settings.setValue("internationalization/language", "en_US");
```

To load that setting back:

```
QSettings settings("organization", "name");
QString lang = settings.value("internationalization/language").toString();
//Now lang contains whatever was inside that setting.
```

Comment: where can I load this function?

Comment: @HafsaElifElalmış The ```QSettings``` API can be included in your code by putting ```#include <QSettings>``` inside the header. Additionally, the API documentation for QSettings is at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html :)